# Installing Apache Maven Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, plugins, maven, installation

I'm currently trying to download an Apache Maven plugin for Eclipse so I can migrate a project from Ant. I've read numerous tutorial sites on how to install this plugin, and most of them offer an update site. Unfortunately, my Eclipse is not finding any of the repositories that are supposedly at the URL's I've been given. Here are some of the one's I've tried:

```
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/
http://mevenide.codehaus.org/maven-eclipse-plugin-plugin/
```

Sadly, all of these haven't proven useful yet, so I'm starting to think that perhaps a certain setting is off or missing within Eclipse itself that is preventing it from finding these repositories. Sometimes, though, it tells me that it is simply unable to read a repository. For example, Eclipse spat out this error a few times when trying to use http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/:

```
Unable to read repository at http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/content.xml.
```

When this happens, it seems as though its "finding" the repository, but it just can't read it... As I've said, I've followed a handful of instructions to downloading the plugin, and none have worked thanks to this initial step. Any ideas?

Comment: Just type Maven in the filter box and it will show up all the available repositories.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

m2eclipse has moved from [sonatype](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) to [eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/).

The *correct* update site is http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/

If this is not working, one possibility is you have an older version of Eclipse (< 3.6).  The other - if you see timeout related errors - could be that you are behind a proxy server.

Comment: Yeah, it seems as if this URL isn't working for me either. I'm pretty sure it's a proxy issue at this point, because I'm currently using Eclipse Indigo Java IDE.

Comment: If you've just turned off your proxy in Eclipse, I find I have to close and re-open Eclipse

Comment: File Not found Error Man

Answer (score 20):

You can install maven from m2eclipse - http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352485/error-m2e-install-in-eclipse incase you get exception installing it with indigo eclipse.

Answer (score 11):

For Eclipse (Helios) the following procedure works - I've tried it:

1. Go to Help -> Install New software
2. Add the following link: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3
3. After results found unselect "sl4j... (optional)"
4. Next

Comment: Worked with Juno too :)

Comment: Only way I found that avoids the Eclipse Martketplace missing osgi dependency issue (good grief - who writes this toy software?) Anyway thank you, definitely worked with Eclipse 3.8

Answer (score 6):

Installed Maven in Juno IDE for Java EE (eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64)

Eclipse -> Available Software Sites -> Maven URL -> http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Following Maven URL did not work and was giving "No software found" error: <s>http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/</s>

Answer (score 4):

I found Maven Integration for Eclipse here.

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

After installing restart eclipse. Worked for me running Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 3):

1. In Eclipse Select Help -> Marketplace
2. Enter "Maven" in Find box and click on Go button
3. Click on "Install" button for Maven Integration for Eclipse (Juno and newer)

With this, maven should get install without any problem.

Comment: This is not working for me, because I have some proxy problem.Is there any other way we can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Installing m2eclipse

All downloads are provided under the terms and conditions of the Eclipse Foundation Software User Agreement unless otherwise specified.

m2e is tested against Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) and 4.3 (Kepler).

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_updatesite_and_gittags for detailed information about available builds and m2e build repository layout.

m2e 1.3 and earlier version have been removed from the main m2e update site. These old releases are still available and can be installed from repositories documented in http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_updatesite_and_gittags

Please note that links below point at Eclipse p2 repositories; you must access them from Eclipse (see how).
Update Sites
Latest m2e release (recommended)
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
m2e milestone builds towards version 1.5
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.5
Latest m2e 1.5 SNAPSHOT build (not tested, not hosted at eclipse.org)
http://repository.takari.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2e/1.5.0/N/LATEST/

Answer (score 1):

This has been moved to a new location now -- and please use the below site for updates.

```
   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04's Eclipse was so broken for me I couldn't get M2E  to install. The only way to fixed it was by using the official tar archive from the eclipse download page after purging all the ubuntu eclipse packages. - Cheers

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 12.04 and eclipse indigo. Can you give instruction how to solve this trouble here [Can't install maven plugin for eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609533/cant-install-maven-plugin-for-eclipse-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

**Eclipse > Help > Eclipse Marketplace...**

Search for `m2e`

Install `Maven Integration for Eclipse (Juno and newer)`. [It works for Indigo also]

Comment: There is no **Eclipse Marketplace ...** in Ubuntu 12.04's `eclipse` (which is Indigo).

Comment: Am using Ubuntu LTS 14.04 | Eclispe Kepler and its there

Comment: This is not working for me, because I have some proxy problem.Is there any other way we can do this ? Is there any link from where we can download the plugin to local and then install from local.

Comment: @JDeveloper In-case of proxy problem, you can't do anything unless your admin give access to you. Else there is no use for Admin :)