# Error: m2e Install In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, m2e

I've been attempting to install Maven Integration for Eclipse and I've received these errors.

```
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui 1.4.0.20130601-0317) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e logback appender 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui [1.4.0,1.5.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender [1.4.0.20130601-0317]
```

My process has been Help >> EclipseMarketplace >> Search "Maven Integration for Eclipse" >> Install (m2e)

Please help.

**Edit**

After running into a plethora of issues, the decision was made to uninstall Eclipse Indigo 3.6.2 and install Indigo 3.7 (as per the standards of the company I currently work at). After taking this course of action, all issues with installations (maven and otherwise) were resolved.

Comment: I'd expect an installation routine to be deterministic. So how should help to install the same software with the same installer again?

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could tell us, where you obtained these files from.

Comment: Hi @PeterWippermann, I originally obtained the files from a coworker, which fixed issues initially but later caused additional issues. I edited my post with the (hopefully) final solution.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue today and found that this question also has recently been asked and answered at the [atlassian forum](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/187906/sdk-tutorial) as well. My solution was to install slf4j based on guidelines [from this blog post](http://javadeveloperslife.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/slf4j-logging-in-eclipse-plugins/) about "SLF4J Logging in Eclipse Plugins".

To extract, here is what I did:

1. Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software
2. Add a new software site:

   - Name: slf4j
   - Url: http://www.fuin.org/p2-repository/
3. Expand "Maven osgi-bundles" and select "slf4j-api"
4. Click "Next" and follow the installation.

After the installation has completed (and Eclipse has been restarted) I was then able to install the maven plugin.

**UPDATE:**

Some of the other answers in this thread now contain links to offical package repositories. I haven't tested if they are working, but if you would prefer to use an official repository, now you know where to find them :)

Comment: FIY, I was trying to install m2e with Kepler and it kept giving me error. So instead I tried with eclipse juno and followed this instruction. And it worked

Comment: Works with Eclipse Helios, version info below:

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Comment: Who hosts this shady looking site? http://www.fuin.org/p2-repository/ It doesn't look like an "official" SLF4J site. Downloading jar files from a random site into a corporate network? Hmm

Comment: @Perce Well, I agree that the site is not the best looking, but by reading through the `About` section and the [blog](http://javadeveloperslife.wordpress.com/) it links to (and which points back to fuin.org) it looks OK to me. Also, fuin.org is on [github](https://github.com/fuinorg) with a lot of contributions. Finally, if you compare the MD5 hashses of slf4j.api_1.6.6.jar (from fuin.org) with [Maven's](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.6) - you will see those are equal. So yeah, even though this is not an offical repo, it seems legit to me based on these observations.

Comment: @Perce As seen in the other answers, there are also official repositories which should be possible to use as well. Since my answer is currently the most upvoted answer I have added an update stating that those repos are also available :)

Comment: @BelahceneBenzaraTahar That's great :) Didn't you forget to upvote then? ;)

Answer (score 28):

Use the software update site as http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.0
That worked for me and got away with the exact same error message.

Comment: Thanks for posting, I found that the update site http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3 also works with no problem.

Answer (score 20):

Plugin team has created a fix for m2e 1.4 & Eclipse Indigo (with this precision : Indigo is no longer officially supported for m2e) :

P2 repository : http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases-for-indigo/1.4/

Reference : [m2e-users mailing list](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg04198.html)

Comment: it seems that this URL is now outdated, it returns 404

Comment: Link is working. The 404 return is also correct. Took me also a while to understand what eclipse is trying to tell. It is not a page but a p2 repo. To see the content one can click on the `Show Directory Contents.` link to see what is inside.

Answer (score 12):

Using Helios, and I used this repository to download Maven Integration For Eclipse with no problems.

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

Answer (score 6):

That mean the folder eclipse/plugins missing "org.slf4j.api_1.6.4.v20120130-2120.jar", so you need copy the file to eclipse/plugins!

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu 13.04, Eclipse 3.8.1.   For Step 3 all I had to do was add the main juno download site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno and m2e can be installed from there.

Answer (score 4):

This is because maven 1.5 is not compatible with current eclipse version.
So we need to use maven 1.4 or 1.3

Steps to install maven 1.4 is below

1)Click Help in eclipse

2)Install New Software

3)Url for the location of site is "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases"

4)Uncheck the checkbox "Show only the latest versions of available software"
  if do not uncheck the checkbox it will only latest version and do not show maven 1.4.

5)Select m2e and slf4j of 1.4 version and click next.

Comment: Thank you Rajeesh, this is what helped me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using eclipse Indigo -- It seems to be missing many files. If you download eclipse Kepler it seems to have the files that are lacking in Indigo. May suggest to switch.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with the latest version of eclipse **Indigo** 64bit. I solved installing the latest version of eclipse **Juno** 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the org.slf4j.api 1.6.4/1.7.2 on the [Orbit repository](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140114142710/repository/), which is more reliable than other third party repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The reason Maven can't resolve slf4j is because Maven can't find it in available software site. That is why the suggestion of @Lasse to use another software site works. I would like to point out that the basic root cause is because the atlassian documentation is out-of-date now. So we can just use the latest version of Maven.
Reference: [Maven for Eclipse (M2E) Installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934503/maven-for-eclipse-m2e-installation-error)