# m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) is missing while adding Maven plugin to Mule Studio

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mule, m2eclipse, mule-studio

I'm new to Mule and I have installed Mule Studio 3.5.0 for Windows. While installing maven plugin from Hep --> Install New Software --> m2eclipse Update Site - http://download.eclipse.org/technolog... i'm getting following error.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: m2e - slf4j over logback
>   logging (Optional) 1.4.0.20130601-0317
>   (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)

If i understand correctly, Mule studio is built on top of Eclipse, i couldn't figure out which version of eclipse is being used for Mule Studio 3.5.0. However i found the similar kind of issue with Indigo 3.6.2 as mentioned here [Error: m2e Install In Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352485/error-m2e-install-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution on thread : [Error: m2e Install In Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352485/error-m2e-install-in-eclipse)

- Install slf4j plugin first from the update site http://www.fuin.org/p2-repository/