# Maven for Eclipse (M2E) Installation error

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e

Error Details:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
>     Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Editors) 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.editor 1.4.0.20130601-0317) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
>       To: org.eclipse.m2e.editor [1.4.0.20130601-0317]`

Getting the above mentioned error when installing M2E in Eclipse. The M2E URL that I used is 
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Comment: Did you try the following: [error-m2e-install-in-eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352485/error-m2e-install-in-eclipse)?

Comment: What version of Eclipse?

Comment: This is Eclipse Indigo specific issue I think. Answer from @HDave is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks Dawid, installing slf4j-api ("Maven osgi-bundles" -> "slf4j-api") via http://www.fuin.org/p2-repository/ Fixed it!

Answer (score 33):

As of late 2011, the M2Eclipse project was donated to the Eclipse foundation by Sonatype and is now called simply M2E. As of the Indigo JEE SR2 release, this plugin can be found in the pre-configured "Indigo" update site contained inside Eclipse, ***so you don't have to add any new update site***.

To install, do the following:

- Launch Eclipse; select the Help->Install New Software menu item.
- Select the "Indigo" update site and wait for the software choices to
  pop up in the table in the lower portion of this "Install" dialog (it
  can take up to a minute).
- In the table, select "General Purpose
  Tools" and then "M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse", click Next and
  finish the installation of the plugin.
- Restart Eclipse as directed.

Comment: worked for me as well - should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi HDave you will help a lot the community if you mark this answer as accepted (the green check)

Comment: @Yoiku - only the person that asked the question can mark an answer as accepted.  The person supplying the answer cannot do that.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, for older Eclipse, like Helios, version 1.5 or 1.4 throws similar error. You can try with 1.3 in that case :

```
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3
```