# Downloading Maven Eclipse Plugin ( m2e plugin)

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

While developing Maven web project, I need to download Maven Eclipse Plugin. 
I used the url:http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases as :  eclipse ->  Help -> Install New Software -> Click Add.

It gives below error :

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui 1.4.0.20130601-0317) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e logback appender 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui [1.4.0,1.5.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender [1.4.0.20130601-0317]
```

Answer (score 7):

hi varun first you try to install subclipse and then m2e.

```
Click Help>>Install New Software
Click "Add..." to add a new software site.
name: subclipse
location: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x 

Click Help>>Install New Software
Click "Add..." to add a new software site.
name: m2eclipse  >>Install
location: http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/1.0
```

Comment: Why would installing Subclipse be needed? m2e does not depend on Subclipse and that is not what the error message is complaining about!

Comment: Following the referenced instruction (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352485/error-m2e-install-in-eclipse) I kept getting the error: requires 'bundle org.eclipse.osgi 3.10.0'. joy's instruction worked for me. Tanks!

Answer (score 3):

This question has been answered before here: [Error: m2e Install In Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352485/error-m2e-install-in-eclipse)

In short you need to install slf4j as m2e is depending on it.