# Can't install maven plugin for eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, maven, ubuntu

I tried install at eclipse Indigo - Version: 3.7.2, Maven plugin.

Here step by step what I did:

Help => Install new software... => Work with => add `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases` location => Tick `Maven integration for eclipse` => next.

But it wasn't finished and pop up:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
```

But when I looking for at Window => Preferences, Maven doesn't exist.

I want to update eclipse to `kepler` version. I added needs repository to

```
Window - Preferences - Install/Update - Available Softsarve..
```

And when I went to `Help - Check for Updates` I saw next error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Equinox p2 RCP Management Facilities Source 1.2.0.v20130604-2046 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.source.feature.group 1.2.0.v20130604-2046)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.I20110613-1736 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.I20110613-1736)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Simple Configurator Manipulator 2.0.0.v20130327-2119 (org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator 2.0.0.v20130327-2119)
    Simple Configurator Manipulator 2.0.0.dist (org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator 2.0.0.dist)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Core Function 1.0.1.dist-8291FXcFLhV8CJ871602A41 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.dist-8291FXcFLhV8CJ871602A41)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator [2.0.0.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Core Function 1.2.0.v20130604-2046 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.v20130604-2046)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator [2.0.0.v20130327-2119]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 RCP Management Facilities 1.2.0.v20130604-2046 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.v20130604-2046)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.2.0.v20130604-2046]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 RCP Management Facilities Source 1.2.0.v20130604-2046 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.source.feature.group 1.2.0.v20130604-2046)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.feature.group [1.2.0.v20130604-2046]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Provisioning for IDEs. 2.1.2.dist-6-Bk8lt6MLqLsEf6-RFpFIpRdhQG (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.1.2.dist-6-Bk8lt6MLqLsEf6-RFpFIpRdhQG)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.0.1.dist-8291FXcFLhV8CJ871602A41]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.I20110613-1736 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.I20110613-1736)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group [2.1.2.dist-6-Bk8lt6MLqLsEf6-RFpFIpRdhQG]
```

***How to solve this and install Maven plugin?***

Comment: Is that the complete error message? I'd have expected to see at least one plugin that can not be loaded.

Comment: @Calon It's all message. Can you explain why this happen?

Comment: Why are you trying to install such an old Eclipse version? Why not using Keppler? Apart from that if you go on the site you mentioned you will see message about a move site which is now: http://archive.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/

Comment: @khmarbaise if it will solve problem? How can I update eclipse version?

Comment: @nazar_art Just simply download Eclipse from eclipse.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the option "Contact all updates sites..." in the Installation Manger and make sure that the download site for Indigo (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo) is checked.

This should be the updatesite containing your m2e Installation anyway, since the downloadsite you used contains the LATEST maven built, which is not 3.7.2 .

If you want to use a newer Eclipse, use KEpler with the updatesite http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler.

If that doesn't work, please post the new error.

Comment: I did what you suggested and really have caught error. I updated question. How can we solve this trouble?

Comment: If you are still running on Indigo, the Kepler updatesite won't work. 
Are you using a local installation that you use alone?
Please check again what IDE Version you are using and confirm that your updatesite matches that version. 

You might want to download a fresh and clean Kepler Version Eclipse and test if you can install maven in that. If it works, you're a step closer to the problem.